# Space between line comment character '#' and start of actual comment in shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, shell

There exist shell scripts where comments have a space between the hash sign and the actual comment

```
# a comment at the beginning of a line
echo foo # a comment trailing after a command
```

and other that do not have one

```
#another comment at the beginning of a line
echo bar #another comment trailing after a command
```

Does this decision have some sort of impact on the actual execution of the scripts or is it (just) a coding style issue?

Comment: After you enabled `hashcommands` via `set -o hashcmds` for recent Bourne Shell versions, A line that starts with `#something` is seens as a special command. But this only applies to the end of the file `$HOME/.shrc` where this feature is usually enabled for interactive shells. The default for all scripts is disabled hash commands. BTW: hash commands include a method to edit shell aliases witout a need to quote the text.

Comment: Another exception is the shebang line (characters hash sign and exclamation mark (#!)) at the beginning of scripts.

Comment: One big difference between the shell and other languages like awk or perl is that there should be a space or non-word token _before_ the `#` in order to be recognized as a comment marker: `echo 3#foo` will print `3#foo` not just `3`.

Comment: @schily I can't find any information about `set -o hashcmds` at https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html or Google. Do you have any link where I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no non-stylistic difference; [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) that, when recognising tokens in the shell,

> If the current character is a '#', it and all subsequent characters up to, but excluding, the next <newline> shall be discarded as a comment. The <newline> that ends the line is not considered part of the comment.

Comment: This is only true as long as you do not use POSIX extensions, see my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any shell in which a whitespace would matter.  For example, in `man bash` it says:

```
   In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which
   the interactive_comments option to the shopt builtin is enabled
   (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), a word beginning with #
   causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to
   be ignored.
```

It specifically says that *all* characters after # are ignored.

Personally, I prefer to put a whitespace after #.